# Where is the bug in this pattern passed to sed?

Tags: sed

I'm using *sed* to replace some strings in some of my files. I'm trying to match a string like **"namespace Foo\BarBundle\Tests\blah\blah"** with this pattern:

`^\\(namespace\|use\\)\s\*Foo\BarBundle\Tests\\(.\*\\)$`

But it's not working. The Complete command goes as follows:

```
sed -i -e "s/$pattern/\1 Tests\\Foo\BarBundle\2/g" <file_name>
```

Where `$pattern` is the pattern stated above. (which is the output from `echo $pattern`).

I've ran it on multiple files to no avail. Is there something wrong with the first pattern?

Comment: what is your sed version? `\b` and `\B` will match word-boundary and other-than-word-boundary in GNU sed and perhaps other versions as well

Comment: in any case, ``\`` is meta character... use ``\\`` to match ``\`` literally

Comment: @sundeep this is used in a script and the "Foo\BarBundle" comes from the input (where I did use `\\`). Appending "\Tests" to "Foo\BarBundle" is handled in the script where I use `\\` as the leading backslash also. I also use double quotes when I want to set `pattern` to the pattern included in the question. Do I have to use 4 backslashes maybe?

Comment: Instead of three , four or a million backslashes, use `\x5c` directly (back slash ascii code)

Answer (score 1):

Use 3 backslashes `\\\` to specify a regular backsplash `\`:

```
pattern="^\(namespace\|use\)\s*Foo\\\BarBundle\\\Tests\(.*\)$"
sed -e "s/$pattern/\1 Tests\\\Foo\\\BarBundle\2/g" <file_name>
```

---

The first two `\\` become one in the shell which then escape the third one `\` in *sed*

Comment: I used four backslashes which I think might be cleaner. Since both double backslashes will get escaped to one in the shell.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use 4 backslashes if you want to match a single backslash - both in standard input and in the script.